# A good npm module for hashing and salting user login/passwd?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, npm

At work, we want to upgrade our node app authentification a little by using a unique salt per user.

We are already using [passport and passport-local](http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password) with our hand-written password validation, storing password hash in DB and salting with a common salt.

I want to upgrade it correctly. One of the first rule of security I know is **not doing it oneself** : https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

However, I'm having trouble finding a decent, trustable npm module to handle that. Searching npm with "salt" or "auth" yielded those modules :

- https://github.com/florianheinemann/password-hash-and-salt
- https://github.com/davidbanham/hashPass

Their documentation is unclear and they have less than 10 stars on GitHub.

Can someone point me to a good module for hashing/salting/checking my passwords ?

Comment: have you checked bcrypt module ?

Comment: @HirenS. This looks perfect. Add it as an answer and I'll select it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Bcrypt (npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

Choose bcrypt module for generating hash with salt. Also note that it will make slow ur node app. Single encrypt decrypt operation takes around 100ms

[edit] Explanation : [How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Comment: Additional confirmation "Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?" http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage using bcrypt seems a good security practice.